# Join two empty tables

Tags: mysql, linux, join

I have two empty tables and i want to join them. Or i want to copy the schema from one and add that schema to the other table.

thanks

```
     select * into dbo.table2 from dbo.table1;
```

Comment: Have you got it what's asked in this question? If yes please let us understand. @PO

Comment: I'm trying to join two schemas from two different tables

Comment: You are trying to join two different tables. okay. But the tables are empty! Better exemplify your use case.

Comment: both tables are empty because i will load the data in the new table that contains the columns from both of the

Comment: Can you drop table2 to begin wtih? and recreate it? or are there indexes and other fields needed? `drop dbo.table2; create table2 as (Select * from table1);`

Comment: i can't :( what about join them?